AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version' when use optim
I use this code to define optimizer but I receive the error.
ctc_loss = CTCLoss(blank=0, zero_infinity=True)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

My full code about is:
# Chuẩn bị loss function và optimizer
ctc_loss = CTCLoss(blank=0, zero_infinity=True)
optimizer = optim.Adam([{'params':model.parameters()}], lr=0.001)

# Quá trình huấn luyện
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        inputs = data[i].unsqueeze(0)  # Thêm batch dimension
        target = torch.tensor([ord(c) - ord('a') + 1 for c in targets[i]])  # Chuyển từ thành chỉ số
        target = target.unsqueeze(0)  # Thêm batch dimension
        
        input_lengths = torch.tensor([inputs.size(1)], dtype=torch.long)  # Độ dài của input
        target_lengths = torch.tensor([target.size(1)], dtype=torch.long)  # Độ dài của target
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Forward pass
        output = model(inputs)
        
        # CTC loss expects log probabilities
        output = output.log_softmax(2)
        
        # Tính toán loss
        loss = ctc_loss(output.transpose(0, 1), target, input_lengths, target_lengths)
        
        # Backward pass và cập nhật trọng số
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        total_loss += loss.item()
    
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}, Loss: {total_loss/len(data)}')

print("Training Complete")

This error says that:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 7
      5 # Chuẩn bị loss function và optimizer
      6 ctc_loss = CTCLoss(blank=0, zero_infinity=True)
----> 7 optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
      9 # Quá trình huấn luyện
     10 epochs = 10

File d:\Projects\Air_writing_words\my_venv\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py:73, in Adam.__init__(self, params, lr, betas, eps, weight_decay, amsgrad, foreach, maximize, capturable, differentiable, fused)
     59     raise ValueError(f"Invalid weight_decay value: {weight_decay}")
     61 defaults = dict(
     62     lr=lr,
     63     betas=betas,
   (...)
     71     fused=fused,
     72 )
---> 73 super().__init__(params, defaults)
     75 if fused:
     76     if differentiable:

File d:\Projects\Air_writing_words\my_venv\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py:367, in Optimizer.__init__(self, params, defaults)
    364     param_groups = [{"params": param_groups}]
    366 for param_group in param_groups:
--> 367     self.add_param_group(cast(dict, param_group))
...
   2213     import importlib
   2214     return importlib.import_module(f".{name}", __name__)
-> 2216 raise AttributeError(f"module '{__name__}' has no attribute '{name}'")

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'

I have reinstalled the torch, but it still didn't fix it.
I check torch version with code:
torch.__version__
Its result is '2.4.0+cu121'. It's satisfy with the CUDA version <=12.3
nvidia-smi
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 546.12                 Driver Version: 546.12       CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650      WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0              14W /  58W |      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |

I just ran it on colab, it worked. I think this error is caused by my computer but I don't know where this error occurs

Can you reduce this to a [mre]? Preferably, that would include any imports and exclude any code that isn't needed to reproduce the problem.

Worth trying with previous version of torch, e.g. 2.1.0. To install it, run following command in your environment (or even create new virtual env): pip install torch==2.1.0.
